# React native move flatlist from one screen to another

Tags: react-native

I have already done firebase with user authentication. Each result is displayed in a flatlist. Upon clicking the heart icon I want to move the selected item to the favorite screen.

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyTLg.png)

```
  <FlatList
     contentContainerStyle={ { alignSelf:"center",}}
        data={Results}
        keyExtractor={(Result) => Result.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          // console.log(item.id);
          return (

            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("ResultsShowScreen", {
                  id: item.id,
                  image: item.image,
                });
              }}
            >
              <ResultsDetail Result={item} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

[Favorites Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpNZw.png)

```
<View>
      <Text> Screen</Text>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by reading the properties of the `route.params` object of your [Favorite Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpNZw.png). Like so:

```js
function Favorites ({route}) {

  const {id, image} = route.params;

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Keep in mind that this will only show the `id` and `image` you are passing when the `TouchableOpacity` is pressed. If you want a list of all the favorites, you need to store them on a data structure like an array (and modify the array when an item is faved/unfaved), and pass that array to the [Favorite Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpNZw.png)

For the complete reference of this feature, you can read the [Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/) page of React Navigation docs.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!. I am now able to pass the required data to the favorites screen. Do you have any resource for saving the list of favorites. Does it require async storage. Thank you.